# Using php5-fpm and nginx in a debian machine

Tags: php, web-applications, deployment, nginx, webserver

I am trying to set up nginx server to run a php app in debian. I followed [this tutorial](http://kevin.deldycke.com/2011/06/nginx-php-fpm-mysql-debian-squeeze-server/) among others. Most seems the same. My recent configuration is based on the link above. When I try to run this php script,

```
<?php
    phpinfo();  
?>
```

I get the same output on the browser instead of php info result. Kindly someone help me figure out where I went wrong.

Note: My error logs are clean,contains details on nginx server start only.

Thank you.

Comment: Your nginx setup lacks the support for PHP... doublecheck you have your `/etc/nginx/php.conf` in place and included in your server configuration

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make sure *php5-fpm* is listening on the correct port you're expecting it to be using. Do a *netstat* listing and see if php-fpm is listening on port 9000:

```
netstat -tulpn
```

You should see a line that looks something like this:

```
tcp   0  0 127.0.0.1:9000  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN   2390/php-fpm.conf
```

If not, check your www.conf file (in */etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf*) and look for the *"listen = ..."* line and make sure it says:

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

I have seen default configurations of php5-fpm use a socket instead of a tcp port.