# Nginx with PHP5-FPM -- .php files giving blank screens

Tags: nginx, webserver, php

I'm banging my head against the wall trying to get nginx up and running with php5-fpm.  I felt that it was a small detail I was overlooking, so I took a break and came back to it a few days later.  Been messing with it for another few hours tonight to no avail.

Anyways, here is the issue:  I have nginx up and running.  It appears to be serving out web pages properly.  for example, the base website of http://www.shidenadvanced.com serves up just fine.  However, the php test I have, located at http://www.shidenadvanced.com/test.php is coming back as blank.  Previously it was coming back as a 502 Bad Gateway.

Through my research I was lead to understand that meant it could not properly route it through the php-fpm.  Not 100% on that.

This is my /sites-available/config:

```
server {
    server_name www.shidenadvanced.com shidenadvanced.com;
    access_log /srv/sites/shidenadvanced/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/sites/shidenadvanced/logs/error.log;

    root /srv/sites/shidenadvanced/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    try_files $uri =404;
    #    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    #    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm5.sock;
    #    fastcgi_index index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/sites/shidenadvanced/www$fastcgi_script_name;
    #}

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Outside of this I have left most of the settings alone.  Not entirely sure what's going on.  Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Are you getting anything in your error logs? Also is the socket present in `/var/run/`?

Comment: **Output of the error logs:**
2013/01/26 05:02:52 [crit] 3647#0: *20 connect() to unix:/var/run/php-fpm5.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 74.110.180.71, server: www.shidenadvanced.com, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm5.sock:", host: "www.shidenadvanced.com"

**--** That is the most recent line.  But that php-fpm5.sock does exist.
/var/run/php5-fpm.sock, that is

Comment: Silly question, just to be sure: you mentioned that you had nginx up and running, did you also start (and configure) the php-fpm daemon?

Comment: I am fairly certain I did.  I have the file /var/run/php5-fpm.sock as I have mentioned.  I also have looked at the /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf to make sure it is listening to that socket.  And when I type "service php5-fpm status" it returns that it is running.  I have tried restarting both the php5-fpm and nginx multiple times.

Comment: Just a follow up:  It seems to be fixed now.  I wound up bailing on the socket approach and just having it listen through TCP (I think that's the right terminology...).  The change I had to make was in the /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf.  I had to change the listen from the socket to 127.0.0.1:9000.  **Reference** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777017/using-php5-fpm-and-nginx-in-a-debian-machine

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: I start php5-fpm deamon and above error disapears :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I made a few changes to the way you are handling fastcgi

```
server {
server_name www.shidenadvanced.com shidenadvanced.com;
access_log /srv/sites/shidenadvanced/logs/access.log;
error_log /srv/sites/shidenadvanced/logs/error.log;

root /srv/sites/shidenadvanced/www;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

# use fastcgi for all php files
location ~ \.php$
{
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

Comment: Upon changing it to this config, it gives me a "502 Bad Gateway" response.  I was at this point originally and thought this meant that it can't find the PHP service at all (although I might be mistaken on that). http://www.shidenadvanced.com/test.php

Comment: I spent a day and a half w/ a new blank page using php5-fpm issue that popped up for me out of nowhere. Adding this line to my php location statement solved the issue for me `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`.

Answer (score 2):

I am personally prefer the socket solution:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/path/tp/myfirst.socket;
```

instead of

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

but you need an fpm config for the host too:

```
[hak-rentrisch_de]
listen = /path/tp/myfirst.socket
listen.owner = hostuser
listen.group = hostgroup
listen.mode = 0666

listen.backlog = -1
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

user = hostuser
group = hostgroup

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
pm.max_requests = 500

php_admin_value[include_path] = .:/var/www/libs 
[...]
```

Kind regards

Comment: I am already using a socket implementation in my output.  What is the second file you mention here?

Comment: The second file is the pool configuration. Look into the nginx config, it has some include to the pool dir(s)